# The method "date" that you're trying to access does not exist in the class declaration

Tags: angular, webpack, tslint

It's kind of silly question but here's one:

> ./SPA/app/foo/foo-list/foo-list.component.ts
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) [19, 56]: The method "date" that you're trying to access does not exist in the class declaration.

I'm using angular with date pipe which is integrated at angular itself.

`{{ item?.created | date:'dd' }}`

And tslint produce that annoying warning. I use webpack with tslint-loader.

Well, any advice? :)

Comment: I am getting the same lint error with custom pipe. Are you able to fix it?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash It was a while and I believe I didn't find a solution. Otherwise, I would post here a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is item not private in your component "foo-list.component.ts" ?

Comment: Item is public. What your suggestions?

Comment: what do you have in your template line 19, and arround ?